# data structure to store unique id on particular date

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures, defaultdict

I have data like `date,id,v_id`. I want a data structure to represent this data in such a way that one `v_id` will be there on a particular date, it should not repeat.

Which data structure should I choose? I thought of using default dict. like in below format.

```
{date1:[{v_id1:id1},{v_id2:id2},{v_id3:id3}],date2:[{v_id1:id1},{v_id2:id2},{v_id3:id3}]}
```

If I'm thinking in a correct way, then how should I implement this? and if there is any other better idea, please most welcome.

Comment: `{date1: {v_id1:id1, v_id2:id2, v_id3:id3}...}`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye thanks, this worked. just asking, don't you think inserting any id in this structure will be time consuming and searching will also take time. would be a great favor if you suggest other such structure.
Thanks

Comment: @ggupta Are you familiar with hash tables? I recommend you take a look at  what they are and how they work.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, not aware about hastables in details :(, surely will look into this. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the `v_id` unique for each date, you should use some sort of hashtable for the nested data structure, which is the underlying data structure  for a dictionary:

```
{date1: {v_id1: id1, v_id2: id2, v_id3: id3}...}
```

Once a date is known, a `v_id` (or `id` given the `v_id`) can be found in *O*(1); you can hardly beat that.

Your actual implementation will look sometime like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
```

Comment: Thanks @Moses, could you please suggest any efficient structure to insert and search for such data?

Comment: @ggupta Dictionaries already implement *key-value* insertion., and the `in` operator can be used for search.